# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server - error on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server error on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I am able to solve by following below steps.


1. Delete the \Documents\IISExpress folder using the following console command: rmdir /s /q "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress"

2. Delete the applicationhost.config file which is placed within the \.vs\Config\ folder in your Visual Studio project root folder.

Comment: Please add details of the error, as we do not have extrasensory perception. Also, adding a comment to clarify your question is not the best approach, just hit the `edit` link (just under the tags) and add the info there, then remove the comment.

Comment: You should post this as an answer, not a comment - and as @PeterB mentioned, you should [edit] your question and include the actual error message so other can find your question and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the \Documents\IISExpress folder using the following console command: `rmdir /s /q "%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress"`
2. Delete the applicationhost.config file which is placed within the .vs\Config\ folder in your Visual Studio project root folder

Comment: Before deleting the files, you might use Jexus Manager to analyze the web project file to see whether you do hit the out-of-sync issue, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html. Otherwise, deletion won't resolve the issue.